SN754410NE overheating when powering 24V and 6V motors with PWM from ESP32
I am using the SN754410NE to power two brushless DC motors SN754410 Quadruple Half-H Driver datasheet (Rev. C) (ti.com). I am using a PWM signal from an ESP32 on the logic pins 1A-4A to accelerate and decelerate the motors and taking good care that I keep the duty cycle max low for the 6V motor. The 24V and GND-BOOST nodes are connected straight to my boost converter outputs. Below is the schematic for my driver setup.

The driver receives 24V for the motors and 5V for logic. This is the 24V planetary gear motor.
The 6V gear motor was just a continuous servo motor that was lobotomized. I had weird problems getting it to work normally straight off the 5V supply line with its normal signal pin to the ESP32 so I just removed the controller and treated it like another brushed DC motor.
Here is the code.
#include <RunningAverage.h>

//pins
int pin_analogR2= 35; //analog input
int pin_driver1A= 12;
int pin_driver2A= 13;
int pin_driver3A= 14;
int pin_driver4A= 15;
int pin_driver12EN= 16; //pwm output
int pin_driver34EN= 17; //pwm output
int pwm_12pins = 255; //24V duty cycle
int pwm_34pins = 30; //6V duty cycle


RunningAverage current_reading(100);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  pinMode(pin_driver1A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_driver2A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_driver3A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_driver4A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_driver12EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_driver34EN, OUTPUT);
  current_reading.clear();

}

void loop() {
  //put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // current_reading.addValue(analogRead(pin_analogR2));  


// DRIVE MOTORS

  digitalWrite(pin_driver12EN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin_driver34EN, LOW);
  for(int dutyCycle = 0; dutyCycle <= pwm_12pins; dutyCycle++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver1A, dutyCycle);
    analogWrite(pin_driver2A, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 24V motor forward accel");

  for(int dutyCycle = pwm_12pins; dutyCycle >= 0; dutyCycle--){
    analogWrite(pin_driver1A, dutyCycle);
    analogWrite(pin_driver2A, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 24V motor forward deccel");
  delay(100);


  digitalWrite(pin_driver12EN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin_driver34EN, HIGH);

  for(int dutyCycle = 0; dutyCycle <= pwm_34pins; dutyCycle++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, dutyCycle);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 6V motor forward accel");

  for(int i=0;  i<= 300; i++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, pwm_34pins);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Maintain 6V motor forward velocity");

  for(int dutyCycle = pwm_34pins; dutyCycle >= 0; dutyCycle--){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, dutyCycle);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 6V motor forward deccel");
  delay(100);

  for(int dutyCycle = 0; dutyCycle <= pwm_34pins; dutyCycle++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, 0);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, dutyCycle);
    delay(20);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 6V motor backwards accel");

  for(int i=0;  i<= 300; i++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, 0);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, pwm_34pins);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Maintain 6V motor backward accel");

  for(int dutyCycle = pwm_34pins; dutyCycle >= 0; dutyCycle--){
    analogWrite(pin_driver3A, 0);
    analogWrite(pin_driver4A, dutyCycle);
    delay(20);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 6V motor backwards deccel");
  delay(100);


  digitalWrite(pin_driver12EN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin_driver34EN, LOW);

  for(int dutyCycle = 0; dutyCycle <= pwm_12pins; dutyCycle++){
    analogWrite(pin_driver1A, 0);
    analogWrite(pin_driver2A, dutyCycle);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 24V motor backwards accel");

  for(int dutyCycle = pwm_12pins; dutyCycle >= 0; dutyCycle--){
    analogWrite(pin_driver1A, 0);
    analogWrite(pin_driver2A, dutyCycle);
    delay(10);
  }
  Serial.println("Drive 24V motor backwards deccel");

  digitalWrite(pin_driver12EN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin_driver34EN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  }

As you can see, I do not run both motors at the same time, and I enable and disable the corresponding channels when one motor is in use while the other is not.
The 24V motor receives a peak of around 22V (as expected from the drop from the bridge) and peaks at around 200mA without load, but the 6V motor only receives around 190mV and peaks at around 400mA without load, which makes no sense to me. I have checked for shorts, which there are none. These readings are from a newer SN754410NE IC as the last one had burnt when I set the duty cycle to 60 instead of 30 (which should be closer to the actual 6V as 30 is too small, especially considering the voltage drop, but it did not burn the IC at 30 so I went with it to be safe.). What else should I try to get this setup to work? I'm planning on putting a heatsink on the IC as I have prototyped it on a protoboard with an adapter, so its body is not in contact with the board. I believe this caused some heat issues due to bad heat dissipation. The PCB I am making for this has the chip in full contact with the copper plane below with a heat sink on top of the IC, I just worry it is not enough because it is a plastic case. But overall, any ideas on what the problem is?

What is the intended usage of U6?

U6 is a current sensor. In my application, my motor stalls at 1.3A and the driver is rated at 1A continuous. I would like to detect when the motor is close to stalling and to shut off power when the current exceeds 1.1A using U6.
